# Returning errors from PL/SQL

Tags: oracle, plsql

Quick and straightforward question:

I am writing a PL/SQL stored procedure. It contains some `execute immediate` calls that might fail. I don't want to raise an error. I would like the stored procedure to finish its execution cleanly and return a list of errors. Something like:

```
for vRecord in vCursor
loop
    begin
        execute immediate 'insert into t(a) values (' || vRecord.val || ')';
    when others then
        -- store the error somewhere to return it!!
    end;
end loop;
```

So my question is: what's the recommended way of returning those errors? A Table? An out parameter?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Wow, i just answered similar question in another thread, strange day so far.  Use a LOG table and use autonomous transactions if you simply want to log errors (or messages):

See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4919437/dbms-output-put-line)

Comment: Thanks! I thought of that. Don't know if it's the best option though. It seems like an OVERKILL to use a TABLE just to return errors... Thanks for the suggestion anyway!

Comment: Never overkill to log errors, good practice ;)  And you have an audit trail of what occurs over time, assuming this is something you'll run on some frequency.

Comment: You really should use something like dbms_utility.format_error_stack||dbms_utility.format_error_backtrace instead of just SQLERRM.

Answer (score 3):

From version 10g Release 2 onwards, you can use DML Error Logging to store all errors in a special table. You can read about it here:

http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e16760/d_errlog.htm#ARPLS680

Some other advice based on the code you posted:

1) It's not necessary to use dynamic SQL here. Just use this instead:

```
insert into t(a) values (vRecord.val);
```

2) It's not necessary to use a loop here. Just use an INSERT/SELECT instead:

```
insert into t(a) select [the query from your vCursor here]
```

Regards,
Rob.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer Rob. I will take a look at DML error logging. Thanks for you suggestions as well. But, what I posted is just a sample code. My actual code **does** need dynamic SQL.

Comment: It is always the best idea to use Oracle's built-in functionality rather than rolling our own.  However, I'm not sure how easy it will be to use DML error logging with dynamic SQL; it depends in what way the SQL is dynamic...

Comment: True. The table - t in this case - should not be dynamic :-)