# Adding logs in stored procedure to display number of records inserted in DB

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures

I have a shell script which calls a stored procedure which is inserting data in the Oracle DB. I takes 4-5 hours to run the procedure. I want to add a log in the stored procedure which would display the no. of records inserted in the DB after a particular interval of time (say in evrey 20 minutes).
Is there a way to add logs in the stored procedure?

Comment: Yes, its a common thing actually.  See my answer [here][1].


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4919437/dbms-output-put-line

Answer (score 0):

It depends how you're doing it. If you're just doing a straight insert only `insert into ... select ...` then no, there's no way. However, if you have some sort of looping in there you can use the [`dbms_application_info`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25788/d_appinf.htm#ARPLS65225) package to record your actions in the V$SESSION view.

I normally do something like this:

```
dbms_application_info.set_module('Updating Blah','Total: ' || <index var>);
```

The first parameter is the `module_name`, which you can view on the `module` column and the second parameter is `action_name`, which is the `action` column in V$SESSION.

Alternatively you can always insert or update a smaller table which tracks what you're doing and can therefore by asynchronously queried.

Comment: Quick additional point; 4-5 hours is 1/6th of a day, which is rather a long time for a job to be running. You might want to look into improving the procedure.