# Getting intermediate spool output

Tags: sql, oracle, spool

Am using oracle 11g, and i have a sql file with 'spool on' which runs for at least 7+ hours, as it has to spool huge data. But spool output is dumped only when the whole sql is finished, but i would like to know is there any other way to know the progress of my sql, or data spooled until that point in time, so that am rest assured that my sql is running properly as expected. Please help with your inputs.

Comment: did you try to spool out to a file? SPOOL file.out

Comment: Yeah, i have tried spooling into the file only, like 'spool spk.log'

Comment: Are you doing it through pl/sql?

Comment: Use a log table.  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4919437/dbms-output-put-line

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you are using `DBMS_OUTPUT`, which always only starts to actually output the results after the procedure completes.

If you want to have real/near time monitoring of progress you have 3 options:

1. Use `utl_file` to write to a OS file. You will need access to the db server OS file system for this.
2. Write to a table and use `PRAGMA AUTONOMOUS_TRANSACTION` so you can commit the log table entries without impacting your main processing. This is easy to implement, and readily accessible. Implemented in a good way this can become a de facto standard for all your procedures. You may then need to implement some sort of house keeping to avoid this getting too big and unwieldy.
3. A quick and dirty option which is transient, is to use `DBMS_APPLICATION.SET_CLIENT_INFO`, and then query `v$session.client_info`. This works well, good for keeping track of things, fairly unobtrusive and because it is a memory structure is fast.

`DBMS_OUTPUT` really is limited.

Comment: Thnx alot TenG, yeah its a PL/SQL and am using DBMS_OUTPUT(Sorry for not mentioning this in the first place). hopefully this should help. Thanks again.