# SQLERRM is being overwritten

Tags: oracle, plsql, error-handling, oracle10g

I'm using SQLERRM. But there are more procedures running parallel, so sometimes SQLERRM is overwritten by other ones. With running parallel I mean I run procedure a and procedure b in the same time.SQLERRM is a global function and it is my problem. If the exception is thrown in both procedures, it could happen, the procedure a modifies the error message in procedure b and procedure b gets the wrong message. 
These procedures are using simple construction:

```
BEGIN
--do something/cutted off
EXCEPTION
        WHEN OTHERS THEN
            write_log(SYSDATE, 'ERROR_1', SQLERRM);

END;
```

These procedures calls write_log , declared as

```
 CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE WRITE_LOG
 (
        TS_START IN DATE DEFAULT SYSDATE,
        ERR_CODE IN VARCHAR DEFAULT NULL,
        ERR_DESC IN VARCHAR DEFAULT NULL
 ) 
 IS

 BEGIN
  INSERT INTO LOG
        ( LOG_TS_START, LOG_ERR_CODE, LOG_ERR_DESC)
    VALUES
        (TS_START, ERR_CODE, ERR_DESC);


   COMMIT;

END WRITE_LOG;
```

How can I avoid overwriting of SQLERRM ? The logs are being written, but the error message is wrong.

Comment: Do you mean the value processed by `write_log` isn't what you expect? How is `write_log` defined - is it referring directly to `SQLERRM` itself or the procedure parameter? By 'running parallel', do you mean `write_log` is declared with `pragma autonomous_transaction`?

Comment: Welcome to the `PL/SQL` world and the common bugs. `EXCEPTION WHEN OTHERS`? A real bug.

Comment: @LalitKumarB - I was really hoping that was a simplification for posting, but I guess not reading it again. I don't think that's relevant to whatever the issue actually is though. It really isn't clear what that is...

Comment: You might be right, but, the error stack will never be the same with an exception block.

Comment: To perfectly debug, it is better to remove the eception blocks from everywhere.

Comment: Please edit your post and include the `write_log` procedure so we can see what's going on in there. Thanks.

Comment: @AlexPoole
I have edited my question.

Comment: @user897237 - SQLERRM isn't a global variable, it's a function. (Unless you've spmehow tried to redefine it.) Are you actually seeing a problem, or do you just think it *could* happen?

Comment: @AlexPoole ok, corrected my mistake. The problem happens, it is  not just a guess.

Comment: Please include the *body* of the function. The definition is helpful, but doesn't help to explain the problem. Thanks.

Comment: The problem might be that the "write_log" procedure needs to be defined as an autonomous transaction, otherwise the insert to the log will get rolled back with the main transaction.  For [example](http://www.oracle-base.com/articles/misc/autonomous-transactions.php)

Comment: @tbone: my problem is not, the fact, that the logs are not there. But the fact, that procedure a logs with the message from procedure b.

Comment: What do you mean by "procedure a" and "procedure b"? All you have posted is a single anonymous block. Also, what do you mean by "parallel" in this case?

Comment: @JeffreyKemp: I run procedure a and procedure b in the same time. Both are using this anonymus block.

Comment: It's impossible to tell why two sessions would conflict without more details. How are you determining that the messages being written are wrong?

Comment: The errors are unique for both procedures.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, get rid of the common bug in `PL/SQL` code.

`WHEN OTHERS THEN` without a `RAISE`  and without any rational logic is just uselss, and nothing less than a bug.

Remove all `exception blocks`, and try again. And, follow good coding practices.

Comment: +1 from someone who's wasted weeks of his life debugging applications that silently fail and don't even record the line number of the error.

Comment: Agreed 100% with your sentiment, but this doesn't answer the OP's question.

Answer (score 1):

The procedure `WRITE_LOG` is not using the parameters passed in to perform the `INSERT`. Try it as:

```
 CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE WRITE_LOG
   (TS_START IN DATE DEFAULT SYSDATE,
    ERR_CODE IN VARCHAR DEFAULT NULL,
    ERR_DESC IN VARCHAR DEFAULT NULL)
 IS    
 BEGIN
   INSERT INTO LOG
     (LOG_TS_START, LOG_ERR_CODE, LOG_ERR_DESC)
   VALUES
     (TS_START, ERR_CODE, ERR_DESC);

   COMMIT;
END WRITE_LOG;
```

In addition, in my opinion logging errors to a database table is absolutely wrong. Because you have a `COMMIT` statement in your logging procedure you're going to commit all changes up to the point of the error which is very likely NOT what you want to do. You can mess around with autonomous transactions if you want, but for my money the best thing to do is log to a flat file.

Share and enjoy.

Comment: The function uses the arguments, was a typo(I have changed some names for simplification). Edited the query.

Comment: When you're posting code please copy-and-paste the code that's really being used rather than re-typing it, which will eliminate issues such as this. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Writing to a log table is very common, but it is standard practice to use an autonomous transaction for logging.  This is because you don't want a rollback in the main transaction to affect the logging, or a commit in the logging to affect the main transaction. (@BobJarvis example is not autonomous).

A simple example is shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4919437/dbms-output-put-line/4921960#4921960).

There are some other things to consider with a log table.  For one, you should have a log_id that is using either a sys_guid (defined on the table) or a sequence on a trigger.  Also, use a context field that the write_log can use to differentiate what procedure (or session) is writing the log message.

Once you add this setup (including the context), then run procedure a and procedure b again (concurrently), and pass in the context the procedure name (a or b).  You will be able to see both a and b log messages in the table.