# advanced queuing for table replication to other database

Tags: oracle, database-link, advanced-queuing

So, I am trying to replicate the data in tables to another database using Advanced Queuing. I created a table on both databases:

```
create table test
(
  id number(10) primary key,
  text varchar2(100)
);
```

then I created the queue

```
create type table_repli_payload_type AS OBJECT
(   rowid_record   varchar2(100)
  , tabelle        VARCHAR2(255)
  , schema         VARCHAR2(50)
);



begin
  SYS.DBMS_AQADM.create_queue_table(queue_table        => 'table_repli_queue_table',
        queue_payload_type => 'table_repli_payload_type',
        multiple_consumers => TRUE);
   SYS.DBMS_AQADM.CREATE_QUEUE (
          queue_name  => 'table_repli_queue',
          queue_table => 'table_repli_queue_table'
          );
       SYS.DBMS_AQADM.START_QUEUE (
          queue_name => 'table_repli_queue'
          );
end;
```

wrote a procedure for the replication

```
create or replace procedure table_repli_callback(
                 context  RAW,
                 reginfo  SYS.AQ$_REG_INFO,
                 descr    SYS.AQ$_DESCRIPTOR,
                 payload  RAW,
                 payloadl NUMBER
                 ) AS

   r_dequeue_options    DBMS_AQ.DEQUEUE_OPTIONS_T;
   r_message_properties DBMS_AQ.MESSAGE_PROPERTIES_T;
   v_message_handle     RAW(16);
   o_payload            table_repli_payload_type;
   v_error varchar2(4000);

BEGIN
   insert into log_table values(sysdate, 'start table_repli_callback');
   r_dequeue_options.msgid := descr.msg_id;
   r_dequeue_options.consumer_name := descr.consumer_name;

   DBMS_AQ.DEQUEUE(
      queue_name         => descr.queue_name,
      dequeue_options    => r_dequeue_options,
      message_properties => r_message_properties,
      payload            => o_payload,
      msgid              => v_message_handle
      );
    insert into log_table values(sysdate, 'ROWID: '||o_payload.rowid_record);

    merge into test@test_link a
    using (select * from test where rowid=o_payload.rowid_record) b on (a.id=b.id)
    when matched then
    update set text=b.text
    when not matched then
      insert values(b.id, b.text);

   COMMIT;
exception
  when others then
    v_error:=sqlerrm;
    insert into log_table values(sysdate, 'ERROR: '||v_error);
    commit;    
END;
/
```

and subscribed it

```
BEGIN
   DBMS_AQADM.ADD_SUBSCRIBER (
      queue_name => 'table_repli_queue',
      subscriber => SYS.AQ$_AGENT(
                       'table_repli_queue_subscriber',
                       NULL,
                       NULL )
      );
    DBMS_AQ.REGISTER (
       SYS.AQ$_REG_INFO_LIST(
          SYS.AQ$_REG_INFO(
             'table_repli_queue:table_repli_queue_subscriber',
             DBMS_AQ.NAMESPACE_AQ,
             'plsql://table_repli_callback',
             HEXTORAW('FF')
             )
          ),
       1
       );
END;
/
```

I played around with inserting/updating data in the `TEST`-table and than executing(with changing ids) this Code

```
DECLARE
   r_enqueue_options    DBMS_AQ.ENQUEUE_OPTIONS_T;
   r_message_properties DBMS_AQ.MESSAGE_PROPERTIES_T;
   v_message_handle     RAW(16);
   o_payload            table_repli_payload_type;
   v_rowid_record varchar2(100);
BEGIN
   select rowid
     into v_rowid_record
     from test
     where id=2;
   o_payload := table_repli_payload_type(
                   v_rowid_record, '', ''
                   );
   DBMS_AQ.ENQUEUE(
      queue_name         => 'table_repli_queue',
      enqueue_options    => r_enqueue_options,
      message_properties => r_message_properties,
      payload            => o_payload,
      msgid              => v_message_handle
      );
  COMMIT;
END;
/
```

It's pretty random if it is working. He always seems to write something into `TABLE_REPLI_QUEUE_TABLE`, but when it is gone, about half the time there doesn't appear anything in `LOG_TABLE` and the data in the second database hasn't changed.

Comment: inserts to a log table should be via an autonomous transaction, [for example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4919437/dbms-output-put-line/4921960#4921960)

Comment: as a start take the commits out, it is best practice to commit outside the procedure.  Take the when others out. Then tell us what error messages show up

Comment: there is no error message, since the procedure is/should be called from the queue, but since half the time there is not even an entry in the log table, it doesn't seem to be called at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error was a strange behavior in TOAD.
I sometimes write test scripts, with ddl, dml, selects, pl/sql-blocks in it and execute them by placing my cursor in a part of the desired command and press shift+F9. It seems like my TOAD just didn't execute the PL/SQL-block although it told me, it did.
I put the PL/SQL-block in another tab and just hit F9 and it worked fine, every time.